# How to choose the right protocol and network connection for using ActiveMQ?

Tags: java, activemq-classic, protocols, message

Recently I started using ActiveMQ to act as a Message Middleware in my new project, this is the first time I try use ActiveMQ, the projects I had participated before used our previous company's inner message framework like Swallow. So before I begin implementing the system, I need to clear some design points.

Cases in our system will use ActiveMQ include sending mail, sending tasks to queue and doing tasks from queue, asynchronous request/response, **so what kind of protocol and network connection is the right choice for our cases?** I list some protocols and network connection options here:

**ActiveMQ protocols**:

1. `MQTT`
2. `WS`
3. `Openwire`
4. `Stomp`
5. `Stomp`

**ActiveMQ Network connections**:

1. `VM`
2. `TCP`
3. `UDP`
4. `HTTP`
5. `Failover`
6. `Discovery`

I will also consider the aspects of HA and cluster for my system, so can anybody gives me some ideas to decide how to choose the protocol and network connection?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Openwire has historically been the default protocol the NIO transport can give performance improvements over TCP so if you use ActiveMQ as your only broker use one of these. However using AMQP means in the future you could possibly use RabbitMQ, another popular Message Broker. There are others, STOMP or MQTT are lightweight, VM is designed to be used when the application resides on the same machine as the broker so gets very high throughput.

As ActiveMQ can enable all protocols by default do some quick tests to gain an idea of throughput on the specific application you are building. Then consider the above points in making a decison.

Regarding UDP, TCP, HTTP I would choose TCP. UDP is unreliable and TCP is more than adequate in sending 1000's per second. HTTP could be useful if your company has awkward firewall rules.

I would wrap this in a failover transport. I have never used discovery but would argue this is more advanced and not required initially as it requires a discovery agent. Its only purpose is too discover the ActiveMQ broker dynamically (although you still have to know where the discover agent is).